# PHP Extracting text from <pre>?

Tags: php, html

I have a .html file which looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{blah blah blah text that I want extracted} </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make a PHP script that will extract the inner text from the `<pre>` tag. I have tried Simple HTML DOM and that hasn't done a single thing it just echos out nothing. Im not sure what im doing wrong here or wether or not I should be using Simple HTML Dom. Heres my code for the PHP script to extract the text from the html file:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('pre') as $element)
       echo $element . '<br>';
?>
```

Any ideas on why its not working?

Comment: You can you phpQuery, this is a jQuery port to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

working DOMDOcument example

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<html><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{blah blah     blah text that I want extracted} </pre></body></html>');
$pres = $doc->getElementsByTagName('pre');
foreach($pres as $v){
   echo $v->firstChild->wholeText.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are fetching is returning JSON, not HTML.

Use [a json parser](http://php.net/json_decode) to handle it.